# Hardware advice for simple wireless embedded application

Tags: microcontroller, wireless, transmitter, receiver

Now, I am going to learn embedded programming in microcontroller. I am going to create a device that will receive signal from wireless transmitter. The range will be less than 30 meters. So, I have some questions about toolkit.

1. What type of transmitter and receiver should I use that receive and send signal up to 30 meter?
2. What kind of microcontroller and board should I use to create embedded system?
3. Do I need any other circuit or device like antenna or anything else?

I am new in microcontroller.

Comment: Is that 30 meters line-of-sight or are there obstacles (trees, or maybe even enforced concrete) in the path? Transceivers that can achieve 30 meter line-of-sight might do only 3 meter between office floors!

Comment: Yes, there may be obstacles in the path.

Comment: Be more specific, or you won't get any meaningful answers.

Comment: After your reply, I have a doubt about Transceivers. So, I can't get single if there any obstacle in the path and the range is more than 3 meters? Suppose, there is wall between the devices then it will not be connected? right @WoutervanOoijen?

Comment: When you say 'less than 30 meters' you have not said anything meaningful yet. No solution will give that range if that 30 meters is solid steel and it extends all around you. So you have to think about what you want to be able to transmit through. The substance is probably more important than the distance. Some substance (a plain glass window) will not be much of a problem. Others (steel mesh window) can be a big problem. I am just trying to get you to specify your requirements properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are new to microcontrollers, your best course of action would be to get an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) (there are several types).  While they are designed for beginners, they also have a lot of flexibility.
[image][image]

Peripherals for the Arduino are called *shields*, and they have many options for doing wireless.  One option you might want to consider is [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth), which can cover up to 100m out in the open, and quite a bit less indoors. You didn't say whether you will be indoors or outdoors.  There are many Bluetooth shields, such as [this one](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/Bluetooth-Shield-p-866.html?gclid=CMyAiLGhkb0CFRBffgodvhoAuw).  In almost all cases, the antenna is already included on the board.

If battery life on the remote device is a factor, you might also want to investigate [Bluetooth Low Energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy), which has a range similar to "classic" Bluetooth but consumes much less power.  It is quite new (there is no native support for it in Windows 7, for example), but since you will be providing both ends of the wireless link, this should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks sir, for your opinion. But, I don't want to make my device discoverable in other devices like mobile, tablet and PCs. Is it possible to make it visible only for my transmitter device?

Comment: @Nimesh Assuming you are going to just make one pair of these devices, then when you set them up, you will put one in discovery mode for just a few minutes and pair the two modules up.  After they are paired, you can make them non-discoverable since they will then have stored the MAC ID's of the other Bluetooth module.

Comment: @Nimesh Will the remote transmitter be some sort of wireless device?  Just wondering if you might be able to get that off-the-shelf.

Comment: Yes, I am going to make just one pair of these devices and transmitter device that works only in that device(receiver). other devices will not be connected to my device.

Comment: But, the problem is that i need to make it discoverable manually. It should be connected automatically when both devices are in range.

Comment: -1 : How does "since you are new to microcontrollers" lead to "you should use an Arduino"? Why not 8051, PIC, ARM, ...?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I am a both a 8051 and PIC fan myself, but I recommended Arduino here because of the ability to add various wireless options using the shields.

Comment: @Nimesh Maybe I wasn't clear -- you only have to make one of the devices discoverable once for a few minutes to enable pairing; once that is done, they will reconnect  when they fall in range without you having to put them back in discover mode again.  That's what pairing is for.

Comment: @tcrosley That's what i want.

Comment: Can I make connection even there are obstacle between the devices?

Comment: @Nimesh Yes, but your range will be reduced; for example, if indoors, and there are walls, I've seen Bluetooth's open-field range of 100m reduced to 10m.  If you are outdoors, and there is a big building in the way, not so good.  If it is just a shed, or a bunch of trees, you should still get 30 to 50m.

Comment: thats fine. 10m is good for me. Then I can go with the bluetooth device. Thanks again @tcrosley.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you are new to micro controller & embedded systems you should start with very basic micro controllers such as 8052( 8051 architecture) or MSP430G2231 (Launchpad kits are available with In system programming) which are very small yet useful and easy to understand. It will be helpful for you to learn the very basic functioning of controllers & you can easily switch to any higher level controllers.

[image]
Since, there are lots of wireless protocols and modules available in the market.
You can start with basic ASK/QPSK transceiver which can be simply implemented using Serial port of the controller & are easily available at cheaper rates than other devices. Or you can use zigbee, level of complexity varies from very simple(peer to peer) to moderately complex(mesh topology).

Range of modules :

Zigbee upto upto 500m
ASK/QPSK : upto 150m
(Ranges vary indoor and outdoor)
No need to use antennas. You can, if you want to improve range little more.

Choose controllers which is being used by many beginners so you can discuss and get help support easily.

Comment: -1 : How does "since you are a beginner" lead to "you should use a basic micro like ..."? Why not arduino, PIC, ARM, ...?

Comment: World is full of possibilities, combinations and permutations. 
8051 is one of the primary architecture in the field of micro-controllers & is very easy to use and understand, once you know very basics OF ANY CONTROLLER you can easily relate or switch to other controllers..
Well, what you are saying is also true selecting that particular device isn't necessary btw OP is free to select & that was my personal opinion.

Comment: What you say holds for AVR and ARM (Cortex) too, and also for PIC if you don't try to understand the assembly language. If you just state your own preference (based on using one particular architecture), say so!

Comment: As I can see there is a Reply button down there and you can make OP available to your suggestions point of view and understanding of Controllers. As simple as that ! I did my job !